# Почему меняются пропорции примитивов directX?

Tags: c++, winapi, directx

Сразу прошу прощения за, возможно, глупые вопросы,я только начал читать про directx.Проблема такова,я создаю окно,и рисую на него квадрат:

```
int Render()
{
    dx_Device->Clear(0, 0, D3DCLEAR_TARGET, 0, 1.0f, 0);
    dx_Device->BeginScene();

    DrawBox(0, 0, 50, 80, 1, 255, 100, 20, 255);

    dx_Device->EndScene();
    dx_Device->PresentEx(0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    return 0;
}
void DrawBox(float x, float y, float width, float height, float px, int r, int g, int b, int a)
{
    D3DXVECTOR2 points[5];
    points[0] = D3DXVECTOR2(x, y);
    points[1] = D3DXVECTOR2(x + width, y);
    points[2] = D3DXVECTOR2(x + width, y + height);
    points[3] = D3DXVECTOR2(x, y + height);
    points[4] = D3DXVECTOR2(x, y);
    dx_Line->SetWidth(px);
    dx_Line->Draw(points, 5, D3DCOLOR_RGBA(r, g, b, a));
}
LRESULT CALLBACK Proc(HWND CheatHWND, UINT Message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (Message)
    {
    case WM_PAINT: // we need to paint? lets paint!
        Render();
        break;
    case WM_CREATE:
        return DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(CheatHWND, &pMargin); // extension of window frame into client area
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0); // We need to use this to exit a message loop
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(CheatHWND, Message, wParam, lParam); // Making sure all messages are processed
        break;
    }
}
```

Но при изменении размера окна,почему то фигура растягивается или сжимается,причем если окно довольно узкое фигура может сразу рисоваться не того размера которого я задал.Почему так происходит,ведь я же четко задаю размеры примитиву?

p.s за что минус?

Comment: Это весьма далеко от [mcve] и вообще мало похоже на directx. А при изменении размеров окна (которое в приведенной оконной процедуре игнорируется) необходимо перевыделять заново задний буффер и соотв. образом модифицировать матрицу проекции.

Comment: @user7860670  ок,щас будет минимальный воспроизводимый пример , и в каком месте это не похоже на directX

Comment: Потому что устройство не знает о том что размер области на которой оно рисует имеет отличную ширину/высоту от той, что ему задали при создании `ID3D11RenderTarget`. А при изменении размеров окна, он будет продолжать рисовать именно в ту область окна, которая ему доступна, и ему плевать на то, какие размеры имеет окно.

Comment: @ヒミコ как это можно исправить?мы же не можем постоянно пересоздавать девайс directx)

Comment: *"и в каком месте это не похоже на directX"* - ну например рисование вызовом Draw у какого-то объекта dx_Line, как будто на конвеере с фиксированными стадиями.

Comment: А вам то что от того что бы будете пересоздавать объект? Главное это сделать правильно.

Comment: А еще тут неопределенное поведение так как Proc может заканчиваться без return